# multiple Grouping in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
create table #temp
    (
    TREE varchar (500), 
    SEED varchar (500), 
    FLOWER  varchar (500),
    Year    varchar (500),
    FLRNO   varchar (500),
    COMMENT1 varchar (500),
    COMMENT3 varchar (500),
    hash AS hashbytes('MD5', [TREE] +  SEED +  FLOWER + YEAR + FLRNO +      
COMMENT1 + COMMENT3)

    )


    insert #temp

    SELECT 'BANANA',    'Nis',  'Tit',  '2004', '57101',    'Sweet Smell     
Flower',  '' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BANANA',    'Nis',  'Tit',  '2004', '57101',    'Bad Smell 
flower' ,  '' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BANANA',    'Nis',  'Tit',  '2004', 'B0019B',   'Sweet Smell 
Flower',  'CATCH ME' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BANANA',    'Nis',  'Tit',  '2004', 'B0019B',   'Bad Smell 
flower',       'CATCH ME' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'APPLE',     'ALE',  'PPL',  '2015', 'PRS13',    'SXT; SWEET 
SMELL FLOWER',  'God' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'APPLE',     'ALE',  'PPL',  '2015', 'PRS13',    'SE; Bad SMELL 
FLOWER',    'CATCH ME' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'APPLE',     'ALE',  'PPL',  '2015', 'PRS13',    'SXT; SWEET 
SMELL FLOWER',  'CATCH ME'
```

HOW can we check that group of TREE,SEED,FLOWER and Year have FLRNO which is exist with all available COMMENT1 present in a group
and 
the same group of TREE,SEED,FLOWER and Year have comment3  which is exist with all available COMMENT1

**for tree APPLE God is not available with "SE; Bad SMELL FLOWER" so entire group exclude from the output.**

expected Output:
/*

```
 'BANANA',  'Nis',  'Tit',  '2004', '57101',    'Sweet Smell Flower',  '' 
'BANANA',   'Nis',  'Tit',  '2004', '57101',    'Bad Smell flower'  ,  '' 
 'BANANA',  'Nis',  'Tit',  '2004', 'B0019B',   'Sweet Smell Flower',      
'CATCH ME' 
 'BANANA',  'Nis',  'Tit',  '2004', 'B0019B',   'Bad Smell flower',    'CATCH ME'
```

*/

-- Query tried but not giving result

```
; WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT [TREE], SEED, FLOWER, YEAR,
          COUNT(DISTINCT hash) AS grp_count,
          --COUNT(*) AS grp_count,
          COUNT(DISTINCT FLRNO) AS part_grp_count,
          COUNT(DISTINCT COMMENT1) AS COMMENT1_grp_count,
          COUNT(DISTINCT COMMENT3)AS COMMENT3_grp_count
   FROM   #temp
   GROUP  BY [TREE], SEED, FLOWER, YEAR
)
SELECT *
FROM   #temp t
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   CTE
               WHERE  CTE.[TREE] = t.[TREE]
                 AND  CTE.FLOWER = t.FLOWER
                 AND  CTE.SEED = t.SEED
                 AND  CTE.YEAR = t.YEAR
                 AND  CTE.grp_count = CTE.COMMENT1_grp_count * CTE.COMMENT3_grp_count * CTE.part_grp_count
                 AND  CTE.COMMENT1_grp_count > 1)
```

Comment: can any one please suggest how to achieve this. if possible

Comment: You should try to fix the question, for example "which is exist with all available COMMENT1 present in a group" doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite unclear what you're trying to accomplish, but at least this will get you that result:

```
select * from temp t
where 
  (
    select top 1 count(distinct comment1)
    from temp t2
    where t2.tree = t.tree
    group by t2.comment3
    order by 1 asc
  ) > 1
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2158/1)

Comment: Thanks. i am trying to acheive The resultset should appear only when fulfill all three criteria
1ST : For a group of Tree , seed, flower and Year there should always more than one distinct FLRNO
2ND:  The number of FLRNO in a group of Tree , seed, flower and Year should available with all available comment 1 in the group
3rd:   For a group of Tree , seed, flower and Year, the number of all comment 3, will also available with all comment1

Comment: 1st is just similar as the comment1 in my answer, read your comment 5 times and can't understand what you're trying to say with the rest.